# SQL-Intersecting nested queries

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL, I'm trying to write a statement that answers the following question: NFL Teams with more wins than their division average that also have more penalty yards than the division average.

I have two separate statements that are able to return each individually (IE: a table that lists teams with more wins than division average, and a separate table that lists teams with more penalty yards than average)

I am running into errors when I try and intersect the two queries however.  'Missing select keyword' is the given error.

```
WITH divisionPenaltyYards AS 
(
    SELECT division
        ,avg(penaltyyards) AS AVGPenalty
    FROM nfl.teams
    GROUP BY division
)
WITH divisionWins AS 
(
        SELECT division
            ,avg(wins) AS AVGWins
        FROM nfl.teams
        GROUP BY division
)
SELECT team
FROM nfl.teams
INNER JOIN divisionPenaltyYards 
    ON nfl.teams.division = divisionPenaltyYards.division
WHERE penaltyyards > AVGPenalty

INTERSECT

SELECT team
FROM nfl.teams
INNER JOIN divisionWins 
    ON nfl.teams.division = divisionWins.division
WHERE wins > AVGWins;
```

EDIT: More info per request

NFL.Teams consists of stats for all the teams in the NFL.
Team, division, wins, penaltyyards...

An example of the data set would include 
`Packers, NFC NORTH, 6, 984`
`Steelers, AFC NORTH, 12, 817` 
and so on.

Desired result would be a table listing all teams that have more wins than the division average, while also having more penalty yards than the division average.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help other people figure out what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second CTE should not begin with the `WITH` keyword. Just `, divisionWins AS`

```
WITH divisionPenaltyYards AS 
(
    SELECT division
        ,avg(penaltyyards) AS AVGPenalty
    FROM nfl.teams
    GROUP BY division
)
, divisionWins AS 
(
        SELECT division
            ,avg(wins) AS AVGWins
        FROM nfl.teams
        GROUP BY division
)
SELECT team
FROM nfl.teams
INNER JOIN divisionPenaltyYards 
    ON nfl.teams.division = divisionPenaltyYards.division
WHERE penaltyyards > AVGPenalty

INTERSECT

SELECT team
FROM nfl.teams
INNER JOIN divisionWins 
    ON nfl.teams.division = divisionWins.division
WHERE wins > AVGWins;
```

There is also no need to use two CTEs here.

```
WITH divisionCTE AS 
(
    SELECT division, 
        avg(penaltyyards) as avgpenalty, 
        avg(wins) as avgwins 
    FROM nfl.teams 
    GROUP BY division
)
SELECT team
FROM nfl.teams
INNER JOIN divisionCTE ON nfl.teams.division = divisionCTE.division
WHERE penaltyyards > AVGPenalty

INTERSECT

SELECT team
FROM nfl.teams
INNER JOIN divisionCTE ON nfl.teams.division = divisionCTE.division
WHERE wins > AVGWins;
```

Furthermore, INTERSECT works here, but UNION would make more sense. Ultimately though, neither are needed:

```
WITH divisionCTE AS 
(
    SELECT division, 
        avg(penaltyyards) as avgpenalty, 
        avg(wins) as avgwins 
    FROM nfl.teams 
    GROUP BY division
)
SELECT team
FROM nfl.teams
INNER JOIN divisionCTE ON nfl.teams.division = divisionCTE.division
WHERE penaltyyards > AVGPenalty
    AND wins > avgwins
```

Lastly, if you wanted to avoid the JOIN you could use window functions:

```
SELECT team
FROM 
    (
        SELECT team, wins, penaltyyards,
            avg(penaltyyards) OVER (PARTITION BY division) as avgpenalty, 
            avg(wins) OVER (PARTITION BY division) as avgwins 
        FROM nfl.teams 
    ) averages
WHERE penaltyyards > AVGPenalty AND wins > avgwins
```

Comment: Great answer, and I appreciate your input.  Anything that makes it work with less code is great.  1 minor note, you forgot to change the name of `DivisionWins` during the join statement to `divisionCTE` when you renamed the CTE.  Otherwise, this worked flawlessly.

Comment: Ah! I certainly did. I have fixed that and added one more option using window functions to perform the averages so that the JOIN can be avoided. Not sure if it will be faster as I'm betting your data is relatively small, but it does make a nice succinct query